# PHP me retorna una fecha adelantada

Tags: date

Buenas noches, soy de Peru. Tengo un problema con la fecha que retorna PHP que al parecer esta adelantada. Estamos sabado 9 de Septiembre y me retorna Sunday (sun) 10 de Septiembre.. Supongo que es por eso de la zona horaria y que el lenguaje es de USA ¿como lo puedo solucionar?

```
date( 'D M Y')
```

Gracias.

Comment: puedes usar lo indicado del GMT de php para calibrar la fecha. http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo solucione usando  el siguiente codigo

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

Espero te funcione

Comment: jajajaja me ganaste pero total, con ese segmento de código se soluciona ese problema, saludos.

Comment: donde pongo eso? ahi mismo donde llamo a la fecha: <?  echo date( 'd m y' ) ;  AQUI LO PONGO????    ?> ¿Y sera la misma hora la de mexico que de peru?

Comment: @cassandra no, no es la misma hora de méxico para perú. Deberás utilizar `date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-5')` o bien `date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima')`, esto antes del `date`